# Magento 1.9 customers receiving old confirmation emails

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

We are having a strange issue in magento 1.9. Our customers are receiving order confirmation emails of the orders which are already completed.

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Try to check your `core_email_queue` table. You could see your email entries there.

Answer (score 1):

Since sometime around Magento 1.9.x (I can't recall exactly) new order emails are queued in the database instead of being sent immediately. A scheduled task (cron job) is then responsible for sending the emails out from this queue.

I would hazard a guess that your cron job has not been running and has now been enabled or fixed, and now all the historical new order emails stored in the `core_email_queue` table are being sent out.

Comment: That's not the case. Cron is running and the customers already have received these email when they ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure this out? We are facing a similar issue which has now also expanded outside of order confirmations into other types of emails sent from Magento. We are sending emails via SES with SMTPpro. I've checked out local email queue which is always empty. I've got copies of the emails in my inbox and I can see that the "late arrival" has been sent from scratch as the template is an updated template instead of the template used in the original email send & received months ago. This would rule out the email just bouncing around in queues for months and makes it look like it has been freshly sent out from the system.